# Flutter User Specific Push Notification Using PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, push-notification

So I am assigned a job in which I am supposed to update the already existing Flutter app
I am told to add User Specific Push notifications, the issue here is the backend of the app is made using PHP and MySQL, and the website for the same runs on PHP  since 2015.
Can someone guide me about how I should go about Making it,
Let's say someone posted a job on the app or a website, the users with matching keys skills of the job receive a push notification about the job posted, similarly, there are more scenarios like these like Messaging as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase.

In flutter app:

1. Install [firebase messaging plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)
2. Get a token using this plugin and send to the server (during authorization or registration).
3. Configure receiving notifications

On server:

1. Bind a token to a user
2. Sends a push notification at the right time ([Firebase Cloud Messaging HTTP protocol](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)).